# How to prevent preview image distortion when using cameraViewTransform

Tags: image-processing, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I am working with a custom UIImagePickerController, and scaling the camera to fit full screen as follows:

```
CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
float cameraAspectRatio = 4.0 / 3.0;
float imageWidth = floorf(screenSize.width * cameraAspectRatio);
float scale = ceilf((screenSize.height / imageWidth) * 10.0) / 10.0;
self.picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
```

I access the preview image using:

```
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

The problem is that the preview image has a distortion and does not look the same as the live camera view.

How can I fix this?